# Call a fetch API which is stored once in using apollo cache?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-cache-inmemory

I have been working on Apollo GQL. I'm using apollo cache to reduce unwanted API calls. The probelm now I'm facing is when i have updated a data i should not re-fetch the data because the API is already called once and stored in cache.

- Thing i wanted to do is either **clear cache for a particular query** or refetch the datas from server.!!
- I can't clear the entire cache, cause i'm calling a lot of APIs

i have to re-fetch the data after the following mutation call.

```
const [
reopenInvoice,
{ loading: reopenLoading, data: reopenData, error: reopenError },
] = useMutation<IReopenData, IReopenVariables>(INVOICE_CLONE, {
onCompleted: ({ invoiceClone: { errors, status } }) => {
  if (!errors || !errors.length) {
    message.success("Invoice Reopened");
  } else {
    message.error(errors.join(" "));
  }
},
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"refetchQueries" is the simplest way of updating the cache.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates/#refetchqueries

```
 const [reopenInvoice, { loading: reopenLoading, data: reopenData, error: reopenError }] = useMutation<IReopenData, IReopenVariables>(
        INVOICE_CLONE,
        {
            onCompleted: ({ invoiceClone: { errors, status } }) => {
                if (!errors || !errors.length) {
                    message.success("Invoice Reopened");
                } else {
                    message.error(errors.join(" "));
                }
            },
            refetchQueries: [
                {
                    query: TO_REFETCH_QUERY,
                    variables: {
                        id: objectID,
                    },
                },
            ],
        }
    );
```

Comment: Now i'm having another issue. it refetch the query. but does not update UI

Comment: Are you sure refetch with same query name ?

Comment: the problem is it update cache , but it doesn't update UI, i used refetch() to solve the issue

Comment: after refetch, cache is cleared automatically. Can you show me how you did refetch?