# Why does parent query not update when component query does?

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

When updating a variable in my application (session.isLoading), one instance of `useQuery` updates but the one found in the parent does not.

```
// NOTHING UPDATES on session.isLoading update
function App({ apolloClient, resetStoreToDefault }) {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CURRENT_SESSION);

    // Handle Query Return
    if (loading) return null;
    if (error) console.log('error', error);
    const { session } = data;
    console.log('app session', session); 

    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            ...
            <Authentication/>
            ...
        </Router>
    );
}


// UPDATES on session.isLoading update
function Authentication(props) {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(INITIALIZE_AUTHENTICATION_PAGE);

    // Handle Query Return
    if (loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>;
    if (error) console.log('error', error);
    const { authenticationFields, session } = data;
    console.log('auth session', session);

    updateSessionLoading({ variables: { loading: true } });

    return (
        ...
    );
}
```

Expects: all instances of `useQuery` to update `data` when `cache.session` updates.

Comment: if you want to update another useQuery instances, you should use refetchQueries.

Comment: Can you look this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58670813/5562701

Comment: From what I can tell (and tried) it only seems to update in the component in which it is called.  I am trying to affect the parent level component at this time.

Any input on that use-case would be appreciated.